# is there a general way to set the record_defaults for tf.decode_csv?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am fairly new to TensorFlow and therefore have a few difficulties.After I finished the pre-process for my data,[because I don't know how to generate batches,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43647676/how-to-convert-the-features-into-on-hot-and-generate-tensor-batches-from-ndarray) I save the data as a csv. And then I try to read it in tensorflow, but while decoding (`'tf.decode_csv'` ),the record_defaults argument is necessary. But there are so many columns in my data, so it really takes time to assign the record_defaults. So how can we just set all the values 0(assuming we don't know the specific numbers of columns)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to find a way to skip/get around that, but seems like there's no way to ignore record defaults.

But since you HAVE to know the length of your row in CSV anyhow in order to read it in Tensorflow, the easiest way I have found so far to get around this is to simply pre-fill the defaults with this one-liner:

```
rDefaults = [['a'] * num_cells_in_your_row]
```

So my data is say ~800 columns in each row, and this way I don't have to address them individually. Also, in my case the data read in needs to be in String format, but you can set the initial values to zero/etc. instead of 'a' in case you need floats...

*** UPDATE:

As discussed, the above doesn't restrict you to case where your data types are uniform across the whole row. Here's how you convert specific cells within the row to the data type you need:

```
rDefaults = [['a'] * num_cells_in_your_row]

def read_from_csv(filename_queue):
    reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=False)
    _, csv_row = reader.read(filename_queue)
    data = tf.decode_csv(csv_row, record_defaults=rDefaults)
    dateLbl = tf.slice(data, [0], [CD]) # portion of the row that is 'String'
    crossLbl = tf.slice(data, [CD], [CC])# Also 'String'
# this part converts the rest of from String to float:
    obs = tf.string_to_number(tf.slice(data, [CD + CC], [SEQLEN]), tf.float32)
    return dateLbl, crossLbl, obs
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: it's a good choice when all the data are of the same dtype,but not the most general one...The 'tf.decode_csv' is really tricky, the dtype and the number of fields are all based on the record_defaults argument , making it not that flexible but unfriedly...

Comment: No, not really. My data types are mixed, and in fact that's why I set the defaults as strings. The trick is to then convert the specific slices of each row to the right data type. I will update my answer with a couple of lines of code that does this for me (so my row is a mixture of Strings and Floats)

Comment: Thank you so much. I get it. when I set `[[1.0] for cl in range((num_cells_in_your_row))]` it returns  '[1.0, 563.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0]'; while `[['a'] for cl in range((num_cells_in_your_row))]' get `[b'1.000000', b'563.000000', b'0.000000', b'1.000000', b'0.000000', b'0.000000', b'0.000000', b'1.000000', b'0.000000', b'1.000000']` . It's the  type of output which is based on the record_default, right?

Comment: oh, I got that in the sources. `Returns:
    A list of `Tensor` objects. Has the same type as `record_defaults`.
    Each tensor will have the same shape as records` thanks~~~

Comment: Yes, it's an encoding issue. In my experience if you convert those directly into floats as I described in the code, it's fine. But if you need the actual string values of some specific cells (which is my case) then you can do it like this: dateLbl_batch[0][0].decode('utf-8'). This example gets rid of the b'' for the first element of the batch and the first cell within that element. If you aren't doing batches, then you don't need one of the dimensions

Answer (score 0):

Here's the most elegant way I've found:

```
record_defaults = [tf.constant(.1, dtype=tf.float32) for count in range(5)] # 5 fp32 features
record_defaults.extend([tf.constant(1, dtype=tf.int32) for count in range(2)]) # 2 int32 features

t = tf.constant([["-0.185027;-0.632726;0.882167;1.906664;0.306666;468794;956042"],
             
["-0.185028;-0.632727;0.882168;1.906665;0.306667;468795;956043"]])

tf.io.decode_csv(t, record_defaults,
             field_delim=';', use_quote_delim=True, na_value='')
```