# (Tensorflow) How to use load_csv_without_header with target_dtype as a String value?

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow

So I want to load a csv file that has no header. All the data in the csv is text. I can't figure out how to use

`tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_without_header(filename=TRAINING,target_dtype="""I want this to be a string""",features_dtype="""This too""")`

but it always throws errors. I've used `dtypes.string`, `np.string` (which doesn't exist), `tf.string`, and a bunch of casting but most of the `tf.cast thing here` need an "x" value.

**How can I import my csv file (with strings!)?** I don't mind using a different method. Is there also a way to convert a string to numpy.float32?

I would also prefer if the strings could be converted to a different format (like float32, or similar. Is that possible?) and then convert them back at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can try using `tf.text_line_reader`, which has a parameter `skip_header_lines`.

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43674569/is-there-a-general-way-to-set-the-record-defaults-for-tf-decode-csv/43680388#43680388) probably does more than what you need, but you can get the gist of what's required easily. The key constraint is that each row should have the same number of columns in your CSV

Since you are required to provide defaults for each cell in the row, if your rows contain both strings and floats/ints, you are better off providing all the defaults as Strings and then converting the needed parts into floats. The other way won't work.